# Sticky position on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, sticky

I'm trying to make a sticky element in my website that it's made in wordpress with a custom template.

I was trying everything, from css (position: sticky) should work. But in my case is not.

Can you help me with this issue?
[This is the structure of the page, on the left the sticky element that I want. On the right, the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Metuc.png)

Thank you you very much for your time.

Comment: Can You give the url ? so i can give you the css for position sticky or just try with top property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked your code.**Position sticky** is not working as because one of the parent div has **overflow:hidden** property so basically position sticky is not working with overflow hidden so please apply below property in your css file and then check

```
<style>
    aside.widget-area.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-4.col-lg-3.order-2-sm-sidebar {
        position: sticky;
        top: 80px;
        height: 600px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    #widthContent {
        overflow: unset !important;
    }

</style>
```